# $window not letting me attach browser refresh event using `onbeforeunload`

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to capture a reload event from a controller. Inside my controller I have the following...

```
refresh = function() {
  console.log("At least we know it ran!");
  if ($window.performance) {
    if ($window.performance.navigation.type === 1) {
      console.log('page reloaded');
    }
  }
  return null;
};
$window.onbeforeunload = refresh;
$scope.$on('$destroy', function(e) {
  delete $window.onbeforeunload;
});
```

But the refresh function is never hit when I push the browser's reload button. What am I missing here?

Comment: Do you have any console errors?

Comment: Can you add a console.log on the scope destroy event?. Could it be that it is executed before the unload??

Comment: I tried debugging but it wasn't hitting the destroy function. There is nothing in the console log.